# yandex maps как фиксировать центр карты при зуме

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно фиксировать центр карты при смене zoom
Такой сценарий
1) Пользователь на ПК фиксирует точку на карте ( точка - центр карты)
2) Пользователь меняет zoom карты через колесо мыши (behavior.ScrollZoom)
3) Нужно чтобы центр карты всегда был в из п.1

Сейчас получается так что центр карты сдвигается на то место, где находится мышка в момент прокрутки колеса.
Чтобы это исправить я делаю setCenter(). 
Выглядит это не красиво, карты постоянно прыгает.
Скажите, как сделать это плавно, чтобы центр карты не смещался при зуме колесом мыши?

Comment: А если запретить ScrollZoom на карте и оставить только контрол зума? Вообще не очень понятно зачем нужна такая функциональность. Если пользователь зумится не в центр карты, то наверно он хочет туда призумиться и кажется, что отбирать у него эту возможность не стоит. Почему центр не должен сдвигаться?

Comment: @se0ga Кейс такой: 1) пользователь ставит точку на карте (центр карты) 2) Затем пользователь задает радиус окружности. Чтобы радиус определялся относительно выбранной ранее точки, ее нужно фиксировать. Иначе она будет постоянно прыгать. Т.к при зуме центр карты смещается.

Comment: А если запретить ScrollZoom на карте и оставить только контрол зума?

Comment: @se0ga будет не удобно на мобильных устройствах. Делаю один код для пк и мобильных.

Comment: Уже начинает всплывать, что это не только для ScrollZoom надо делать=) Есть три способа у пользователя изменить зум вместе с центром карты: мультитачзум(разведение пальцев на карте), ScrollZoom, даблкликзум(двойной тап по карте). Вы хотите, чтобы ваша логика действовала на все 3 способа?

Comment: @se0ga Да, на все возможные

Comment: Таких возможностей нет, но вы можете написать своё поведение реализовав [`IBehavior`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IBehavior-docpage/).