# Zoom c фиксированным центром в Yandex Maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, zoom

Подскажите как можно зафиксировать центр карты при зуме любым способом (pinch, wheel, dblClick)?
Тут уже задавали этот вопрос и рекомендовали реализовать свое поведение IBehavior
[yandex maps как фиксировать центр карты при зуме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966942/yandex-maps-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Но возможно за 4 года реализовали такой функционал? Если нет, то где можно найти доку или примеры по реализации своего поведения?

Comment: А какой смысл Яндексу разрабатывать спец-метод для частного пользовательского запроса? Возможность отключить встроенные поведения они дали, реализация собственных сценариев доступна по отслеживанию интересующих вас событий. Вот пример рисования прямоугольника вместо поведения "rightMouseButtonMagnifier" например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1508589/386299